# Connecting Spring Boot running on gcloud VM to cloud SQL instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

im trying to connect spring boot running on google cloud vm to cloud mysql using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

this is the end of the stacktrace, i dont know hot to copy the whole stacktrace through SSH in browser

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultMySqlJdbcInfoProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/sql/GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$MySqlJdbcInfoProviderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.CloudSqlJdbcInfoProvider]: Factory method 'defaultMySqlJdbcInfoProvider' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A database name must be provided.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.CloudSqlJdbcInfoProvider]: Factory method 'defaultMySqlJdbcInfoProvider' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A database name must be provided.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A database name must be provided.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.DefaultCloudSqlJdbcInfoProvider.<init>(DefaultCloudSqlJdbcInfoProvider.java:39) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.sql.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$MySqlJdbcInfoProviderConfiguration.defaultMySqlJdbcInfoProvider(GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration.java:87) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 76 common frames omitted
```

I've found some articles and other answers about this on StackOverflow, made sure my settings in application.properties are correct but still getting same error. Don't know where to search next.

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=teamplanner
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://34.107.103.23:3306/teamplanner
spring.datasource.username=teamplanner
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
server.port = 8080
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=teamplanner-springboot-rest:europe-west3:teamplanner-springboot-rest-mysql
```

please help

-----------------EDIT
Here's the database name, user and connection properties
[image]

[image]

[image]

Dependency versions:

this is the parent dependency for cloud gcp, it defines the version for `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql` dependency. While developing on my own pc I was connecting to MySql installed on my pc, I didnt have `spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies` and `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql`, only `mysql-connector-java` and everything was working perfectly.

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and this is for the spring boot starter dependencies

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
```

I am able to successfully connect to mysql from my cloud VM SSH with this command 
`mysql --host=34.107.103.23 --user=teamplanner --password` then it prompts me for password, i enter xxxxxxxxx and I'm connected.

Comment: Can you share your cloud SQL configuration (especially the database page) and the version of the dependencies?

Comment: added some info

Comment: I bet on a conflict in resource definition. Can you try comment this line `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://34.107.103.23:3306/teamplanner`?

Comment: i commented out the whole line, also tried changing to ``jdbc:mysql://34.107.103.23:3306``. Same error - ``A database name must be provided.`` 
I'm trying to simply deploy my rest api so i can add the project to CV and employes can check it if they want. Maybe you'll recommend somewhere where i can host it for free if we can't fix this error on google cloud ? I looked at heroku but it has that sleep feature, where your app will go to sleep after 30 mins of no incoming requests. Employers might not wait for it to boot up after sleep and think it doesnt work.

Comment: At the opposite, did you also try to comment the `spring.cloud.gcp.sql.*` lines?

Comment: yes. tried commenting out both, then only one of them, then the other. nothing changes.
weird, just seems like it doesnt see the database-name setting

Comment: if i comment out ALL of the properties in application.properties nothing changes at all. is it possible that in compute engine spring boot app doesnt read the appliaction.properties ? maybe i need to set the properties in environment properties or something ?
 or maybe ``spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql`` requires to create some other .properties file for cloud sql properties ? I've only ran programs from intellij on windows, so i'm not sure about any of this, related to comput engine and linux

Comment: Is it working on windows? Where is located your application.properties file? How do you run your app on compute?

Comment: on my windows pc i haven't tried with cloud ``spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql``. On my pc i only tried with MySql installed on my pc, mysql-connector and spring data jpa and it worked. The applications.properties file was in src-main-Resources. i copied project to compute engine, added the cloud dependencies to pom.xml and added properties to application.properties, didn't move any files. 
I run with ``mvn spring-boot:run`` on compute engine

Comment: also, I've just now tried using ``@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`` on the main class annotated with ``@SpringBootApplication`` on my pc the program started and ran correctly, in compute engine i got this error
``FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist``

Comment: And the file is present in src/main/resources on the compute engine? and you get the source on compute engine through git?

Comment: yes i got it through git.  on my pc i had Resources folder capitalized. maybe i created it on my own when i made the project few months ago. on my pc it always worked.
on compute engine just now i renamed it to resources without capital letter and the error went away(another one appeared, but probably unrelated)

Comment: Windows is case insensitive, linux case sensitive.... Big up to Microsoft!! (or not :-( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my PC when I create the project from spring initializr I must have created Resources folder manually with capitalized R. For months I've been running the project from IDE on windows and had no problem. When I moved project to compute engine and started running it with `mvn spring-boot:run` the application wasn't reading anything from Resources folder because it's not named according to convention as it should be "resources" without capital R. IDE must have done something so that application would read from capitalized folder. Renaming the folder fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this same issue using the PostgreSQL spring boot starter, but with slightly newer versions.  I am using version 2.0.5 of the spring-cloud-gcp dependencies, and 2.5.5 of spring boot.

Strangely, I think I noticed that the order of the properties in the properties file itself might actually be an issue for the starters.  If my properties file looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=${sm://projects/212050278585/secrets/postgres-user/versions/1}

#name the application
spring.application.name=data-svc

spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=service-db
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=gcp-project-331021:us-central1:gcp-poc
```

Then I receive the error in the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A database name must be provided.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:289) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.sql.DefaultCloudSqlJdbcInfoProvider.<init>(DefaultCloudSqlJdbcInfoProvider.java:41) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.sql.CloudSqlEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(CloudSqlEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:86) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
```

But if I re-order the properties to look like this:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=service-db
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=ascendant-pixel-331021:us-central1:gcp-poc

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=${sm://projects/212050278585/secrets/postgres-user/versions/1}

#name the application
spring.application.name=data-svc
```

The difference being that my `spring.cloud.gcp.sql.*` properties appear first in the file.  I know its weird, but it seems to make a difference for me.

Comment: excellent.. work out for me too.. thanks for your finding but did you get it why it is working on this way??

Comment: I don't know that there is a great answer except maybe for inspecting the Spring bootstrapping.  I have a memory of seeing this type of behavior before and although there appears to be "no good reason" for it, I would guess it has a lot to do with order of precedence for settings and config parameters.

Comment: yeah.. totally understood, ideally this should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The error must be in the application.properties class. Change it like this.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://34.107.103.23/teamplanner?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=teamplanner
spring.datasource.password=**********
```

This must be work. Here what happens is you use local MySQL server port number in front of the database URL. No need of adding port number as 8080. If it shows error as 8080 is already in use then only add another port number. Otherwise by default it takes port as 8080. 
Add this dependency to the **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Then problem must be in the database name. "teamplanner" must be your cloud database instance name. Your database name might be another one just double check it. If you still having the problem upload your code to the github provide link. So that I can go through it and find out the issue.

Comment: could you please check my last comment under my main post ? where I talk about @PropertySource ? i think that might be the real issue, the settings of the compute engine environment not seeing/reading application.properties at all

Comment: I have updated my answer with a dependency just add it to the pom file and rerun code.